# $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n$

Tags: solution-verification, summation

[How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4820444/819094)

2 days ago,someone asked this question and I have tried it.But the question was closed and I can't reply there.So I have posted the following to know whether my approach is correct or not.

> How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n$ ?

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\frac{k+1+ n}n+\frac{k+2+ n}n+\frac{k+3+ n}n+\cdots+\frac{k+n+ n}n]$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\frac kn×n+\frac{1+2+3+\cdots+n}n+\frac nn×n]$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[k+\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}2}n+n]$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[k+\frac{n+1}2+n]$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[k+\frac{3n+1}2]$

$=(1+\frac{3n+1}2)+
(2+\frac{3n+1}2)
+(3+\frac{3n+1}2)
+\cdots+(n+\frac{3n+1}2)$

$=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)+\frac{3n+1}2×n$

$=\frac{n(n+1)}2+\frac{n(3n+1)}2$

$=\frac{n(4n+2)}2$

=$n(2n+1)$

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me. You can write your proof more slickly if you stick to $\Sigma$ notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.

It can be simplified a bit by noting that the sum of all terms involving $k$ and the sum of all terms involving $j$ have the same value (which in turn can be seen by exchanging the order of summation for the terms involving $j$).

So I would argue as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac kn + \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac jn + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} k + \sum_{j=1}^{n} j + n^2 \\
&= 2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n^2 \\
&= n(2n+1) \, .
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

@Martin R's solution is very elegant. For me, if you were to give me $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{k+j+ n}n$ when I didn't have pen and paper, I'd have done the following:

There are $n^2$ terms. The minimum is $\frac{1+1+n}{n}=\frac{n+2}{n}$; the maximum is $\frac{n+n+n}{n}=\frac{3n}{n}$. So the average is $\frac12 \frac{4n+2}{n} = \frac{2n+1}{n}$. So the total is $n(2n+1)$, because everything is linear here.